# Story about a woman forced to have a procedure which disconnects the hemispheres of her brain

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to find a story I remember reading many years ago, likely in the early to mid-1990s. Not certain about the length or publication date. I believe it was shorter than a full-length novel, but it could have been either a standalone novella or something short enough to be part of an anthology. I also don't have any recollection of the ending, so it's hard to gauge the overall length. It's possible I read it in one of the anthologies of scifi short stories/novelettes collected by my grandmother (mostly from the 1950s/60s), but I'm not sure about that at all.

In the story, a young woman is adopted (or coerced?) into a group of women where she is required to undergo a ritual/surgery, in which the connection between the two halves of her brain is severed, and she is fitted with a sort of half-mask that blocks out sensory input on one side of her head. The intent is that her ability to communicate is disconnected from her ability to experience and form new memories (she is unable to speak about anything she experiences after the procedure), so that she can serve as something like a courtesan to powerful leaders/politicians without fear that she will share their secrets.

Part of the story focuses on her interactions with other women in the group, who I believe had not had the same procedure, but may have had other specialties.

I think this is probably an obscure one, but the details are unique enough that I'm hopeful someone might remember it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is this a short story or a book, or are you unsure?

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure - I believe it was shorter than a full-length novel, but it could have been either a standalone novella or something short enough to be part of an anthology. I also don't have any recollection of the ending, so it's hard to gauge the overall length

Comment: Yet another story about a person with a severed corpus callosum, apparently written without knowledge of the optic chiasm.

Comment: I remember this. Possibly one of the entwined stories in the first of Catherynne M. Valente’s Orphan’s Tales books?